# Is the conditional probability $P( S=a_i |\, T=a_i, X=x ) \le$ (or $\ge$) $ P( S=a_i |\, T=a_i )$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $Y$ be a positive continuous random variable (r.v.). We define $S$ as a variable that depends on the value of $Y$. If $Y \in [0,b_1]$, then $S=a_0$, If $Y \in [b_1,b_2]$, then $S=a_1$ and when $Y \in [b_2,\infty]$, then $S=a_2$. We suppose that $Y$ is a function of another r.v. $X$. We associate variable $T$ to $X$, as: If $X \in [0,b_1]$, then $T=a_0$, If $X \in [b_1,b_2]$, then $T=a_1$ and when $X \in [b_2,\infty]$, then $T=a_2$.

The conditional probability $P( S=a_i |\, T=a_i, X=x )$ represents the probability to get $S=a_i$ such that we know that $T=a_i$ and $X=x$; it's obvious that $x$ is in the interval that yields $T=a_i$.  On the other hand, $P( S=a_i |\, T=a_i )$ is the probability to get $S=a_i$ such that we (only) know that $T=a_i$.

Does the fact of knowing $X=x$ increase or decrease the probability ? In other words, is $P( S=a_i |\, T=a_i, X=x ) \le$ (or $\ge$) $ P( S=a_i |\, T=a_i )$, for $i=0,1,2$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to tell without knowing the relationship between $X$ and $Y$. $P( S=a_i |\, T=a_i, X=x )$ is $0$ or $1$ depending on whether $X=x$ leads to $Y\in[b_1,b_2]$, whereas $P( S=a_i |\, T=a_i )$ could take some intermediate value, depending on the relationship between $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: In my case, $X=|G|^2$ and  $Y=|G+H|^2$, where $G$ and $H$ are $\mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma^2)$ and $\mathcal{CN}(0,1-\sigma^2)$ (with $\sigma^2<1$) distributed, respectively. I don't understand why $P(S=a_i|T=a_i,X=x)$ can just be $0$ or $1$.. I think this probability is  lower bounded by some $p_{min} >0$ and upper bounded by some $p_{max} <1$. Am I right ? Note that $P(S=a_i|T=a_i,X=x)$ depends only on $|G|^2$,  and its expression, for $a_1$ for ex, can be given by $F(b_2)-F(b_1)$, where $F$ is the CDF of a scaled non-central chi squared distribution.

Comment: @din: You wrote that $Y$ is a function of $X$. In this example, $Y$ is not a function of $X$.

Comment: Yes, I think "dependent" is the right word.. Could you plz tell me if my statement about bounding the probability by $p_{min}>0$  and $p_{max}<1$ is correct ?

Comment: @din: Sorry, I don't have an answer to that. My answer relied on your statement that $Y$ is a function of $X$. If you like, I can delete it so you can get an answer to your actual question.

Comment: No, it's my fault. Anw thank you.